# Can I automatically call handleSubmit in response to a state change using redux-form?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I would like to have a two part submit strategy for my redux-form. First, the user called submit on the form which calls a validation method. The response might have some warnings. I want the user to see the warnings, if any, and optionally continue with another submit that will be a real POST to the server rest api.

If there are no warnings, I would like the component to submit automatically. I am trying to kick this off from the `componentWillReceiveProps` method.

The problem is that `nextProps.handleSubmit(this.doSubmit2of2);` does not call `this.doSubmit2of2`. Execution just steps over that call.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {        

    //boolean that indicates validation just occured against the server
    if (nextProps.storeWithValidation) {

        //the user hit submit, first it was validated, if no issues, go ahead and try to create
        if (nextProps.storeValidationOk) {
            //fire off create store
            nextProps.handleSubmit(this.doSubmit2of2);
        }
        else {
            //there are validation issues of some kind, let the user see them
            //do nothing here and let the render method do its thing with the props
        }
    }
}
```

I have found the discussion here: https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/67, but in my case the submit is happening as result of a particular server response. Also, I realize that there are validation features of redux-form. Am I designing too far outside of the intended framework convention?

Also, I have thought of redesigning my server api, but I would like to know how far I can go with this current approach of automatically resubmitting after a response from the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand you want to submit the form remotely after a response from the server. You can create a remote submit following this [example from the docs](http://redux-form.com/6.5.0/examples/remoteSubmit/). Then you can `dispatch(submit('yourFormName'))` whenever you want to as many times as you want to.

Comment: Thanks, I'm actually following this solution. The key seems to be to perform branching logic in the submit method. I'll post my solution later.